# Gatsby theme i18n markdown doesn't change language when toggle

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, gatsby, react-i18next, gatsby-plugin

I'm using both plugins, [gatsby-theme-i18n](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-theme-i18n/) and [gatsby-theme-i18n-react-i18next](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-theme-i18n-react-i18next/)

I think `gatsby-theme-i18n-react-i18next` work fine. But `gatsby-theme-i18n` for markdown files don't work, possibly I don't understand well enough so

I can change language for `Layout`, `Template` (gatsby-theme-i18n-react-i18next) but I can't change language for `markdowns` (gatsby-theme-i18n)

I toggle between `en` // `th` to change language like so

[image: problem]

gatsby-config.js

```
...
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
  options: {
    name: `products`,
    path: `${__dirname}/src/products/`,
  },
},
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-mdx`,
  options: {
    extensions: [`.md`, `.mdx`],
  }
},
{
  resolve: `gatsby-theme-i18n`,
  options: {
    configPath: require.resolve(`./i18n/config.json`),
    defaultLang: `en`,
  }
},
...
```

gatsby-node.js

```
const path = require('path')
exports.createPages = async ({ actions: { createPage }, graphql, reporter }) => {
  const productTemplate = path.resolve('src/templates/Product.js')
  const result = await graphql(`{
    product: allFile( filter: {
      sourceInstanceName: { eq: "products" } 
      ext: { eq: ".md" } 
    } ) {
      nodes {
        childMdx {
          frontmatter {
            slug
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }`)
  if (result.errors) {
    reporter.panicOnBuild(result.errors)
    return
  }
  result.data.product.nodes.forEach(({ childMdx: { frontmatter: { slug } } }) => {
    createPage({
      path: slug,
      component: productTemplate,
      context: {
        slug: slug,
      },
    })
  })

}
```

Layout component ( toggle to change language )

```
import { LocalizedLink } from 'gatsby-theme-i18n'
export default function Layout({ children, slug }){
  return (
    ...
    <LocalizedLink to={slug} language="en">en</LocalizedLink>{'//'}
    <LocalizedLink to={slug} language="th">th</LocalizedLink>
    ...
  )
}
```

Template to hold markdowns

```
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'
import { MDXRenderer } from 'gatsby-plugin-mdx'
import { LocalizedLink } from 'gatsby-theme-i18n'
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next'
import React from 'react'
import Layout from '../components/Layout'
export default function Product({ data: { mdx: { body, frontmatter } }, pageContext }){
  const { t } = useTranslation()
  return (
    <Layout slug={frontmatter.slug}>
      <h3>{frontmatter.title}</h3>
      <MDXRenderer>{body}</MDXRenderer>
      <LocalizedLink to="/">{t('back-to-menu')}</LocalizedLink>
    </Layout>
  )
}
export const dataquery = graphql`
  query {
    mdx {
      body
      frontmatter {
        slug
        title
      }
    }
  }
`
```

translation data file (markdown)
[image: markdown]

./i18n (config)
[image: config]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [template of the i18next official documentation](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/themes/blob/master/starters/example-react-i18next/src/templates/blog-template.js) you need to provide the locale in your template query:

```
export const query = graphql`
  query($locale: String!, $slug: String!) {
    mdx(
      fields: { locale: { eq: $locale } }
      frontmatter: { slug: { eq: $slug } }
    ) {
      frontmatter {
        slug
        title
      }
      body
    }
  }
`
```

*Note: remove the exclamation mark of (`$locale: String!`) if the code breaks.*

Since it's not passed as a context in the [`gatsby-node.js` query,](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/themes/blob/master/starters/example-react-i18next/gatsby-node.js) I assume that the plugin modifies the GraphQL node by adding this required parameter (because of the exclamation mark at: `$locale: String!`), allowing you to render each post when the language changes.

In addition, among this configuration, you need to provide the `<MDXProvider>` component in your `<Layout>`:

```
const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation()
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <header>
        <LocalizedLink to="/">{t("home")}</LocalizedLink>
      </header>
      <main>
        <MDXProvider components={components}>{children}</MDXProvider>
      </main>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Comment: thank you, but when I add those parts, it gives me errors `Cannot read property 'body' of null` in the `Template`, in the GraphiQL shows `Variable \"$locale\" of required type \"String!\" was not provided.`

Comment: Have you added this configuration? https://github.com/gatsbyjs/themes/tree/master/starters/example-react-i18next/i18n

Comment: Yes, I have. I think I'm good for config parts, anyways I'll add to the question

Comment: That `locale` should be provided then. There's something not properly copied from the starter.

Comment: oh! I think I didn't put <MDXProvider> thank you a lot

Comment: I was about to post it! (I will update it anyway). If the issue has been solved please consider accepting/upvoting the answer

Comment: I've added to the Layout. But I still get errors when I change to English. But for other language (th) works fine

Comment: Add the missing configuration (or at least not provided) for https://github.com/gatsbyjs/themes/blob/master/starters/example-react-i18next/gatsby-config.js#L32

Comment: Yes for plugin 'gatsby-theme-i18n-react-i18next' works fine I think. Let see the first picture (Toggling) in the question, now when I toggle to `en` I get errors instead

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228397/discussion-between-ferran-buireu-and-zummontt).